# SQL Query to return results from related 3 tables with the correct groupings and joins

Tags: sql

The problem (and data) relates to people registering interest in wanting to buy a house, they are known as a ‘prospect’.  A person/prospect can register interest:
•   via a few methods (website, telephone, visit)
•   once or many times on different days (repetition)
•   for zero, one or many locations specific location(s)

**The Data Structure**
*tblProspectHistory* Table – A history of all events for a specific prospect, these are not limited to just events related to registering interest (i.e. WEBENQ = Web Enquiry = website) but can be anything relating to the prospect further along the process i.e. MERGE, CORRES a prospect has been contacted or a follow up action has been allocated.

This is just a sample of the data as the table holds 100K records and for one prospect there are usually circa 100 event records

[image: tblProspectHistory Table Example]

*tblProspectPerson* – Essentially a link table but can contain more than 1 person that is the same prospect i.e. 2 different people (usually a couple like husband and wife) are the same prospect.  However, there is always a flag that identifies the ‘main’ contact and there can only be one (the system ensures that)

[image: tblProspectPerson Table Example]

*tblPerson* – Details about the person(s)

[image: tblPerson Table Example]

One key thing to understand regarding the data structure and how a prospect can register interest is that if the **same** person registers interest at different time, they will get a different ProspectID.  So, to identify if different prospect records are actually the same prospect/person the email address needs to be used (i.e. if different prospect records ProspectIDs have the same email, they are the same prospect/person).

**Requirements**

What I want is the following (per prospect but only 1 prospect showing):

[image: Example Output Required]

**Location**: a 4 digit code which identifies the location
**Event**: the method of how interest was registered: website, telephone, visit
**Count**: just the value 1 for each row as the data is subsequently being fed into PowerBI
**Date**: the earliest date that the person registered interest in for a specific location
**Email**: the unique identifier of the prospect, who it is
**So this is telling me for each prospect what location(s) there were interested in (no location and/or specific locations), when they were first interested in each location and the method (event) that interest was registered.**

I believe I can get 90% of what I want with the following:

```sql
SELECT
       tblProspectHistory.[Location]    AS [Contract]
       ,1                               AS [Event Count] 
       ,MIN(tblProspectHistory.[Date])  AS [Event Date] 
       ,tblPerson.Email                 AS [Email]
FROM tblProspectHistory
        INNER JOIN tblProspectPerson    ON tblProspectPerson.ProspectID=tblProspectHistory.ProspectID AND tblProspectPerson.MainContact=1   -- Only gets the 'main' contact
        INNER JOIN tblPerson            ON tblPerson.PersonID=tblProspectPerson.PersonID
WHERE 
    tblProspectHistory>='2021-07-01'                        -- Only interected in the last 2 years worth of data
    AND tblProspectHistory.[Event] IN ('WEBENQ',’TELENQ’,'VISIT')   -- Only want the events that relate to registering an interest 
    AND CHARINDEX('@',tblPerson.Email)>0                    -- Filters out some invalid email addresses (bad data)
GROUP BY tblPerson.Email, tblProspectHistory.[Location]
```

This returns the below (without the event)

[image: Output Generated]

My problem that I can’t work out and have been trying for days going about in circles is **how do I also return the ‘event’ data?**

•   I can’t simply add tblProspectHistory.Event into the select statement as it is not part of the ‘group by’ (aggregate)

•   I can’t add event to the ‘group by’ as it would give wrong results i.e. if interest for the same location was registered twice with different events a group by would split this as 2 records, I don’t want that I just want to know what the event was when interest was first registered

•   I can’t aggregate it as it will just return the lowest/highest (if MIN/MAX was used) event NOT related to the corresponding location/date
If I join another instance of tblProspectHistory to return the event then I need to join onto this new instance using joins to the correct/corresponding record.  I have tried do that by joining

Location, Date, Email but it returns incorrect results as these are not capable of identifying the exact single record.  It sounds like I need to be joining using ID fields as that will truly find the exact record to join to.  I have tried this but get in such a knot that it hurts my brain and can’t get it to work.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.  This is my first time asking on here so I apologise if I have done anything wrong and will of course listen to guidance on what I should do if I were to ask for help again.

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all relevant data to your question as editable text. formatted appropriately (code, tables, etc)

Comment: You could use a subquery finding first event, something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/xZOcbBQy), hard to test without input in text format and matching required output. Subquery uses row_number() and takes first row.

Comment: @NickW - Thanks, I can see my question in not very readable.  I pasted from a word document and it just translated horribly, so I manually formatted as best I could.  I've had another go at formatting which has improved it but not good enough as I can't get the pictures to work (saving now gives an error about '10 reputation'.  I'll have another attempt..

Comment: @3N1GM4 Thanks for sorting the pictures, my company is blocking the URL so am trying to get them unblocked so I can see them, but everyone else should see them no problem

Comment: Please not my original comment about editable text - if you use images then no-one can copy the data if they want to use it to try out a solution. So please add the data as text, formatted as tables, not images

Answer (score 0):

@Ponder Stibbons thank you for your answer. While I didn't implement your solution exactly, the ROW_NUMBER() OVER function you stated was the answer to this problem. I implemented it as a CTE as per the below:

```
WITH CTE_DATAProspectHistory AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person.email, ProspectHistory.contract ORDER BY ProspectHistory.date ASC) AS Ranking
        ,ProspectHistory.id_prospecthistory
        ,Person.email
        ,ProspectHistory.contract
    FROM ProspectHistory
        INNER JOIN ProspectPerson   ON ProspectPerson.id_prospect=ProspectHistory.id_prospect AND ProspectPerson.maincontact=1
        INNER JOIN  Person          ON Person.id_person=ProspectPerson.id_person
    WHERE ProspectHistory.date>= '2021-07-01' AND ProspectHistory.event IN ('ENQUIRY','WEBENQ','TELENQ','VISIT') AND CHARINDEX('@',Person.email)>0 

)

SELECT
    ProspectHistory.contract    AS [Contract]
    ,ProspectHistory.event AS [Event]
    ,1                      AS [Event Count]
    ,ProspectHistory.date AS [Event Date] 
    ,Person.email       AS [Email]
        INNER JOIN CTE_DATAProspectHistory  ON CTE_DATAProspectHistory.id_prospecthistory=ProspectHistory.id_prospecthistory AND CTE_DATAProspectHistory.Ranking=1
        INNER JOIN coins.ProspectPerson ON ProspectPerson.id_prospect=ProspectHistory.id_prospect AND ProspectPerson.maincontact=1
        INNER JOIN Person           ON Person.id_person=ProspectPerson.id_person
```

Thank you again, I have other users for this solution